# Css changed when loading webpage through Apache

Tags: html, css, apache

I am trying to run apache on ubuntu and create a website. When I simply open the webpage in Chrome from the Documents folder it opens fine and looks good. But when I open it either from the var/www/html file or by searching my ip address through Chrome some of the css has not loaded, not all of it but just some of it. Here the cancel button has been moved even though the code is almost exactly the same as the login button.

```
#login {
    left: 559px;
    top: 161px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Open Sans", monospace, sans-serif;
    color: #1E1E31;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#cancel{
    left: 654px;
    top: 161px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Open Sans", monospace, sans-serif;
    color: #1E1E31;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[image: This is the not working css]

This is what loads through Apache. It is difficult to see but Cancel has moved up to top left and the background has a white strip at the side and other small differences.

[image: This is how it should look]

This is how it looks when normally opened in chrome

Comment: do you perhaps try to load multiple css files? Could you open up chrome's dev tools (ctrl+shift+i) and check the console for errors?

Comment: I highly doubt Apache would be picking and choosing what CSS rule sets to load. What is more likely is your code is missing a character or has one extra.

Comment: I have tried the console and no errors are shown and the css works perfectly fine when not loaded through apache as shown in the pictures above

Comment: do ctrl+shift+i and find out where the element is. would be more helpful to find the answer

Comment: What do you mean by find out where the element is? I have put the css for the cancel element in the question